# setRGB() in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, pixel

I am using setRGB() for changing the values of the pixel of an image.

```
int rgb=new Color(0,0,0).getRGB();
image1.setRGB(i,j,rgb); //where i,j is the boundaries of the image
```

Here,i am setting all the pixel values with white. But the change is not getting reflected in the image. Any One knows about the `setRGB()` how it works?

Comment: May be there is another error or you went a wrong way. So please post more code.

Comment: A couple of points..

- Color(0,0,0) will be black
- setRGB sets an individual pixel in an image, not the whole image

Comment: rgb color chart http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/#PA

Comment: What is `image1`? FYI: values RGB `0,0,0` are mapped to _black_ while RGB values `255,255,255` are mapped to _white_

Comment: Try `setRGB(0,0,0)` and let us know the result.

Answer (score 26):

White is in RGB 255,255,255 so:

```
Color myWhite = new Color(255, 255, 255); // Color white
int rgb = myWhite.getRGB();

try {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("bubbles.bmp"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            img.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
        }
    }

    // retrieve image
    File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
}
catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer so the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Color col = new Color(newValue, newValue, newValue);
            image1.setRGB(i, j, col.getRGB());
```