# Java - setRGB in BufferedImage isnt changing to the correct color

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I cant seem to get bufferedimage's .setRGB to work correctly:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try 
{
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("icons/br.jpeg"));
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
}

for(int x = img.getWidth()-1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    for(int y = img.getHeight()-1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        Color b = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        img.setRGB(x, y, b.getRGB());
    }
}

//Save New Image
File outputfile = new File("icons/newestSave.jpeg");
ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", outputfile);
```

This is br.jpeg: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ifp3.png

And this is the outout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK3tS.jpg

The output should be solid white, since the program should be changing every pixel to 255, 255, 255.

Comment: RGB value 255, 255, 255 means "completely white", not "solid black".

Comment: I fixed my post but it still doesn't explain why the output is solid red. In fact changing the rgb value of b doesn't change anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setRGB() in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951646/setrgb-in-java)

Comment: I can reproduce the problem from the **PNG** image you posted imgur. But your code claims to be reading a **JPG** picture. If I save the PNG as JPG, it works fine. The reason it doesn't work as a PNG is because you used an indexed color model with only he colors blue and red in it, so it can only have these colors in the output.

Comment: I thought that was the problem Erwin, but I made an image with black and white in it and tried to make the entire image white but it didn't work, so I didn't think it was the color model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source image is of type TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED (use img.getType() to show the type), you need to save the image in type: TYPE_3BYTE_BGR

```
BufferedImage i = null;
BufferedImage img = null;
try 
{
    i = ImageIO.read(new File("icons/br.jpeg"));
    img = new BufferedImage(i.getWidth(),i.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
}

//copy the image
img.getGraphics().drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);


for(int x = img.getWidth()-1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    for(int y = img.getHeight()-1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        Color b = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        img.setRGB(x, y, b.getRGB());
    }
}

//Save New Image
File outputfile = new File("icons/newestSave.jpeg");
ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", outputfile);
```

Comment: The problem is that the OP is not reading a *jpeg* file, as jpeg does not support an indexed color model. If the OP were reading jpeg, like the code says, this problem wouldn't be there.

Comment: At first I was using .png and that had the exact same problem. I knew it had something to do with the color model but I couldn't figure out how to change it or even find out what the color model was.